# comma delimited text file into array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct

This is a homework exercise in C which is driving me bananas! I've been researching it for almost two days and have yet to get it working, so any help is mucho appreciated!!

Here's the scenario:
I have a comma delimited text file which looks like this:

```
(2005 TS15),2013-Apr-07,15.2,0.0391,8.0,0.0205,20.61,20.61,1890,21,13,APO*,0.479,M
(2010 GM23),2013-Apr-13,3.9,0.0099,0.9,0.0022,13.14,13.12,61600,24.7,7,APO*,0.195,M
(2009 SQ104),2013-Apr-22,27.8,0.0714,27.8,0.0714,8.16,8.15,67300,20.9,19,APO*,0.408,S
(2012 XF55),2013-Apr-22,32.7,0.0841,32.7,0.0840,7.33,7.33,15600,22.5,7,APO*,0.446,M
```

There are 10000-ish records in the file (its data relating to near-earth-objects).

I need to be able to find the 10 largest objects/ 10 closest objects etc so my plan was to read the data into an array of structs, each struct being based on the columns in the file. I've created the struct and created instances of it to fill from the file.

My issues are in the general function at the end... I think...

I've tried initializing a the full array of structs to a blank instance of the struct but nothing worked there....

I tried reading in each line as a character string and then tokenising it based on the "," limiter but I couldn't figure how to save the token to each element of the struct (that's the end section which is commented out...)

I tried using `fread()` to read the file into the array of structs but nothing happened there either (that's the end section which is commented out...)

My code is below. If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd be really grateful!! (I hope its formatted ok. If i haven't explained the issue properly let me know and I will!!!)

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <math.h>

    #define RECORDS 10972    /* number of records in the file */

    typedef struct {
        char *objectName;
        char *CADate;
        double NomDistLD;
        double NomDistAU;
        double MinDistLD;
        double MinDistAU;
        int VRel;
        int Vinf;
        int NSig;
        float HVm;
        int ref;
        char *ObjClass;
        double Diameter;
        char *Type;
    } NEO; 

    NEO textFile [RECORDS];
    NEO passing[RECORDS];


    void menu();
    void countFile (FILE*fptr);
    void general (FILE*fptr);


    int main (void)
    {
        char filename[50];
        int choice;

        FILE* fptr;

        printf("Enter name of file to open: \n");
        scanf("%s", &filename);

        fptr = fopen(filename, "r");
        if (fptr != NULL)
            printf ("File %s opened succesfully!\n\n", filename);
        else
            printf ("File %s not found!\n", filename);

        countFile(fptr);

       do
       {
     menu();
     choice= 0;

        while(choice <1 || choice >5)
        {
            printf("\nChoose an option from the above (1-5):\n");
            scanf ("%d", &choice);
        }
            switch(choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    printf("function largest\n");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("function closest\n");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    printf("function largest KE\n");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    general (fptr);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
    }

    while (choice !=5); 
        printf("\n\nProgram Exiting. Goodbye!\n\n");

fclose (fptr);

return 0;
    }



    void general (FILE*fptr)
    {
int count= 0,  fileEnd= 0, i= 0, test= 0;
char **neoArray;
char hold[200];    /* string to hold tokenised strings */
char temp[10000];   /* string to hold each record as it is read in */

char *pToken;
const char *delim = ",";    /* define delimiter to tokenising each record */

passing->objectName = "";
passing->CADate = "";
passing->NomDistLD = 0.0;
passing->NomDistAU = 0.0;
passing->MinDistLD = 0.0;
passing->MinDistAU = 0.0;
passing->VRel = 0;
passing->Vinf = 0;
passing->NSig = 0;
passing->HVm = 0.0;
passing->ref = 0;
passing->ObjClass = "";
passing->Diameter = 0.0;
passing->Type = "";


for (i=0; i<RECORDS; i++)
{
    textFile[i] = passing;
}
    }


      /*  while (!feof(fptr))
{
    test = fread(&passing, sizeof(NEO), 1, fptr);

    if(test != 0)
    {
        printf("\n%s %s %f\n", passing[0].objectName, passing[0].CADate, passing[0].NomDistLD);
    }
}


/*while(!feof (fptr))
{
    for (i=0; i<RECORDS; i++)
    {

        fscanf(fptr, "%s", temp);

        pToken = strtok(temp, delim);
        {
            strcpy(textFile[i].objectName, pToken);
        }

        pToken = strtok(NULL, delim);
        while (pToken != NULL)
        {
            strcpy(textFile[i].CADate, pToken);
        }

        pToken = strtok(NULL, delim);
        while (pToken != NULL)
        {
            textFile[i].NomDistLD = atoi(pToken);
        }

        printf("\n%s %s %f\n", textFile[i].objectName, textFile[i].CADate, textFile[i].NomDistLD);
    }

    rewind (fptr);
}
    }
```

Comment: You can't use `strcpy` as you don't allocate the string in the structure. You _can_ use `strdup` instead (i.e. `textFile[i].objectName = strdup(pToken);`) You also don't need to initialize the array, just keep track of the count of loaded entries.

Comment: I think I'm actually going to cry... it seems to have worked!! My allocation code (for want of a better descritption) is now: while(!feof (fptr))
 {
  for (i=0; i<RECORDS; i++)
  {

   fscanf(fptr, "%s", temp);
   
   pToken = strtok(temp, delim);
   {
    textFile[i].objectName = strdup(pToken);
   }

   pToken = strtok(NULL, delim);
   {
    textFile[i].CADate = strdup(pToken);
   }

   pToken = strtok(NULL, delim);
   {
    textFile[i].NomDistLD = atof(pToken);
   }

Comment: so, thanks Joachim for the strdup tip! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is very probably that you copy strings into random areas of memory, since you never initialize the `objectName` and `CADate` pointers.

You're probably better off replacing those pointers with actual arrays:

```
char objectName[128];
char CADate[128];
```

Comment: Thanks unwind (I went with strdup and that appears to have worked!)

Answer (score 1):

I'd read in each line

Then scan forward until finding the ,.  Replace each , with a \0.  Keep a count of each ,

Use the count to call a different sscanf function to load the different fields into the current struct.  The string types of fields would need strdup'ing, to allocate the memory for them.

As a quick test have a shorter version of your csv file ( say 4 lines ) and use the assert feature to check that expected values are getting into the struct

This kind of problem is better done using a scripting language like perl or python

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for that Vorsprung, I used a test file and it made it easier to debug (D'oh!) I used strdup as Joachim suggested and it appears to have worked.